# How to remove the section number from References?

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, numbering, starred-version

I am using the following for the bibliography part:

```
\bibliographystyle{APA} 
\bibliography{Bibliography/mybib}
```

and I am getting a section number for the reference part. How can I remove it (I just want to have the title References without any number before it)?

Here are the coding structure

```
 \documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper,10pt]{article}
 \usepackage{natbib}
 \usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
 \usepackage{etoolbox}
 \apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\scriptsize}{}{}
 \newcounter{numbersec}
 \renewcommand{\section}[1]{\par\noindent\stepcounter{numbersec}
 \par
 \vspace{6pt}
 \noindent\textbf{\large   \arabic{numbersec} \hspace*{0.3cm} #1 }
 \par
 \vspace{2pt}
 }
 \renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{
 \par
 \vspace{6pt}
 \noindent\textbf{#1}
 \par
 }
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}[1]{%
\par
\vspace{6pt}
\textbf{#1.}
}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
```

... the body of the file...

```
\bibliographystyle{APA} 
\bibliography{Bibliography/mybib}
```

Comment: What class are you using?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  what document class are you using, and how do you launch the bibliography?  the answer might be as simple as using `\section*{References}`, but that often depends on the document class

Comment: Thank you for your welcome. I am very new to LaTex. Actually I am using a conference template in which the documents starts with \documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper,10pt]{article}. I put all the article information into mybib file. This is all I do! @barbara beeton

Comment: @saeedi Do you think you could put a minimal example code which still shows the undesired effect so that we could work on that one?

Comment: @MMA I have now added some more details to the original question including the coding segments

Comment: Why are you redefining all sectioning commands in that way? Starred versions are not defined...

Comment: @saeedi Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

The apparent redefinition of `\section` is problematic in a number of ways. It disables the cross-referencing mechanism and does not provide for ToC entries or headers. Worse, it does not preclude page breaks immediately after a section heading. And -- as Karl Koeller has pointed out -- it does not provide a starred (non-numbered) version. As the `thebibliography` environment of the `article` class relies on `\section*`, your template will result in a numbered bibliography section (which will display an unwanted asterisk after the number).

I recommended to abandon the template and to use either the standard `\section`(`*`) command or a modified version which isn't missing essential features. *In case you absolutely have to use the above, deficient template*, add the following to your preamble to provide a starred, non-numbered version of `\section`:

```
\usepackage{suffix}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\section*[1]{%
\par
\vspace{6pt}%
\noindent\textbf{\large #1 }%
\par
\vspace{2pt}%
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\newcounter{numbersec}
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
\stepcounter{numbersec}%
\par
\vspace{6pt}%
\noindent\textbf{\large \arabic{numbersec} \hspace*{0.3cm} #1 }%
\par
\vspace{2pt}%
}

\usepackage{suffix}
\WithSuffix\newcommand\section*[1]{%
\par
\vspace{6pt}%
\noindent\textbf{\large #1 }%
\par
\vspace{2pt}%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{APA}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]